# How to integrate external accounts in connector settings

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I'm working on integrating an existing online service into teams. While authentication works using the client javascript SDK, I was wondering if there is any way to integrate the account configuration more elegantly into teams.

For example connectors form GitHub and others show the connected external account in the 'My Accounts' section in the connector configuration dialog. When inspecting the page it also seemed to me as if they were using a more integrated configuration experience.

Is there a way to utilize this functionality and is there any good documentation on it or is it only possible for 'partners'?

Thanks for your time,
Gelx

**EDIT:**

I assume now that this kind of integration is not available to third parties since there is no documentation on it.
I do have some issues with configuring the connector though. I have followed the steps outlined in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors-creating#integrating-the-configuration-experience) but the configuration fails to save.

I try to explain the issue in more detail here: [GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/Ge-lx/3cc8dffcac77e08e7accef2ca0172286)

I tried setting up a new connector in the dashboard and made sure to include the required domain in the valid domains list.
Now i get this error:

```
{
  "errorType":"HttpAntiForgeryException",
  "errorMessage":"An unexpected error occurred. Please try again.",
  "errorMessageFromProvider":null,
  "providerName":"",
  "host":"VI1P190MB0446",
  "requestId":"d07c70de-f942-4e16-9d69-fbb9b3469f96",
  "time":"\/Date(1550150816383)\/",
  "launchUrl":null
}
```

## EDIT 2:

My current error output is:

```
Received error from connectors {  
   "seq":1550476872815,
   "timestamp":1550481952912,
   "flightSettings":{  
      "Name":"ConnectorFrontEndSettings",
      "AriaSDKToken":"d127f72a3abd41c9b9dd94faca947689-d58285e6-3a68-4cab-a458-37b9d9761d35-7033",
      "SPAEnabled":true,
      "ClassificationFilterEnabled":true,
      "ClientRoutingEnabled":true,
      "EnableYammerGroupOption":true,
      "EnableFadeMessage":false,
      "EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList":false,
      "EnableDomainBasedTeamsConnectorList":false,
      "DevPortalSPAEnabled":true,
      "ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage":false
   },
   "status":500,
   "clientType":"SkypeSpaces",
   "connectorType":"284913c1-6326-4c87-b687-bd7ef58dc163",
   "name":"handleMessageError",
   "nonPIIInfo":"{\"exception\":{}}"
}
```

The following config is generated by my configuration page:

```
{
  configName: "Notifications for collection \"Mars Expedition\"",
  contentUrl: "https://b5e5904f.ngrok.io/msteams/connector-landing",
  entityId: 101,
  removeUrl: "https://b5e5904f.ngrok.io/"
}
```

Comment: Are you looking [Connector's inline configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/connectors/connectors-creating#integrating-the-configuration-experience) experience? Could you please provide some screenshot of what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm working on. It seems to me though, as if other connectors have a more integrated configuration experience (e.g. showing connected accounts).
This post is concerned with the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905064/how-to-create-a-connector-with-configuration-loaded-from-web-solution-for-micros

Comment: Is this kind of integration available to third party apps?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Assuming you have to implement the configuration as described in your link - I ran into some problems getting that to work. I added some details to my question. I think the Issue is the connector not updating its validDomains

Comment: Here is [sample code for connector](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-cshar). Could you please share your Connector Id and configUrl?

Comment: I have had a look at the samples yes. Is it required to call getSettings() after saving the settings and before calling `saveEvent.notifySuccess()`?

I need to retrieve the webhookUrl before saving the settings as the entityId will be generated when registering the webhook with our service.
I noticed the URL is already provided in the `getSettings()` before saving the configuration.

This is my connectorId:
  fc17fd7e-877d-4e97-b2f4-1af37262aace  

My configUrl is here (although very slow since unpackaged for development):
https://c878f667.ngrok.io/msteams/tab-landing

Comment: You can go ahead and use the URL to get entity id from your service. However this webhook URL will only work after calling setSettings(). Your ngrok url is expired.

Comment: Please share the updated ngrok url if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Yes I am still facing issues, although not quite the same. During my initial post I had created the Connector from the AppStudio in Teams using a non-O365 account. If I understand correctly this might have been an issue. 

The current setup is: App registration (c83e1005-3259-4f65-9de6-f687e233ecd1) created with a outlook.com account. The connector (284913c1-6326-4c87-b687-bd7ef58dc163) is now created using a o365-subscribed account and the configuration URL is https://b5e5904f.ngrok.io/msteams/connector-landing

Thanks for your help

Comment: The loading times are quite horrible to be honest. This is due to missing packaging during development

Comment: I could not login using my account to test it. Any alternatives?

Comment: @Gelx- I could see that it's showing b5e5904f.ngrok.io as part of your valid domain. Test once and share the request/response details if it fails again.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT How did the login fail for you?
I just tried again and still receive the same error. I will append it to the OP. My debug output tells me that the configuration is being saved correctly, I will also add the generated settings object to the OP.

Comment: What really baffles me is that it did work sporadically. After having to change the tunnel URL I could not get it to work again despite changing nothing else.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I am not quite sure. Sometimes it works, other times (especially after having to change the tunnel url) it does not.
I am not changing anything except the URL.
Can you confirm if the connector configuration takes a while to fully update maybe?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I am experiencing the issue at the moment with the new staging setup. I had it working yesterday and only changed urls in the configurations. 
My current connector id is "284913c1-6326-4c87-b687-bd7ef58dc163" and the configuration url is "https://staging.zenkit.com/msteams/connector-landing?iframesource=msteams".

Can you please look into this?

Comment: @Gelx- I could not login into 'Zenkit' tenant. Is this connector only for Zenkit members?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT You can login with Zenkit or any of the supported oAuth providers including Azure AD. 
It is working now, though...

Comment: @Gelx- If you are no longer facing this issue can we consider this resolved?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Yes lets consider it that.
Still the configuration/registration of connectors seems buggy and is not what I would have expected from a big, established company selling business products.